# How do I add item [1] in a list to item [1] in another list if both have item [2] in common?

Tags: python, nested-lists

My apologies if this has been asked somewhere already. In that case, I'd appreciate a link.

I'm trying to add items from one list to items in another list if they have a similar item in the list.

Note: This is an Intro to programming course. I am not educated on anything very advanced (I've never used a panda, for example).

I've Googled for days. My class textbook is, unfortunately, inadequate for the task. If I just needed to add all the items in a list, or one item from each list based JUST on it's index within the list, I'd be golden.
That's not the case, though.

I was provided a shell program that already defined the main module. Part of that imported a CSV file. Each line of the file was imported as a list within a list. There are 3 items in each list.

```
Examples:
    [  
    [Monday,4.95,Beverages]  
    [Monday,12.95,Food]  
    [Tuesday,4.95,Beverages]  
    [Wednesday,4.95,Beverages]  
    [Thursday,31,Food]  
    [Friday,45,Food]  
    [Saturday,23,Food]  
    [Saturday,12.5,Entertainment]  
    [Friday,25,Entertainment]  
    ]
```

This is what was provided.

```
def summarize_by_weekday(expense_list):  

    """  
    Requirement 3 to display the total amount of money spent on each  
    weekday, aggregated per day.  
    That is, display “Monday: $35”, “Tuesday: $54”, etc., where $35 is the  
    sum of dollar amounts for all Mondays present in the data file,   
    $54 is the sum of dollar amounts for all Tuesdays present in the  
    data file, and so on.  
    :param expense_list:  
    :return: None  
    """
```

I have tried a lot, and discarded them as I went. So, I can't say
everything I've tried.
Since starting over again, though, I've gotten this much:

```
def summarize_by_weekday(expense_list):  
    print ("Summary by weekday:")  
    totAmt == 0  
    for item in expense_data:  
        day = item[0]  
        amount = float(item[1])  
        category = item[2]  
        for line in expense_list:  
            if day == "Monday":  
                totAmt += amount   
                print ("Monday: $",totAmt)
```

My Error
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'totAmt' referenced before assignment

I also tried this:

```
for item in expense_data:  
    day = item[0]  
    amount = float(item[1])  
    category = item[2]  
    totAmt == 0  
    for line in expense_list:  
        if day == "Sunday":  
            totAmt = map(lambda x: x + x, amount)  
            print ("Sunday: $",totAmt)  
        elif day == "Monday":  
            totAmt = sum(float(amount))  
            print ("Monday: $",totAmt)
```

My Error
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'totAmt' referenced before assignment

The results should print kind of like this.

```
Summary by weekday:  
Sunday: $DDD.CC  
Monday: $DDD.CC  
Tuesday: $DDD.CC  
Wednesday: $DDD.CC  
Thursday: $DDD.CC  
Friday: $DDD.CC  
Saturday: $DDD.CC
```

(where $DDD.CC = the total amount in dollars and cents.)
Even better if the $DDD.CC can be left justified

I don't really need the whole thing written out for me. I'm not looking to have someone do my homework for me.
Something like "Your code is wrong. Try using this," where "this" is as little code as possible to get me on the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The assignment operator is `=`, not `==`.

Comment: Perhaps use a dictionary with the day as the key and the accumulated charges as the value.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have recommended a dictionary as you are probably not that far along in your studies. You would probably need a running total for each day of the week. And an `'if' .. `'elif` structure to determine the day of the week and which day's running total you would need to accumulate. like `mon_total += amount` or `tue_total += amount`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a value to a variable you use '=' , the '==' is for comparison

```
def summarize_by_weekday(expense_list):  
    print ("Summary by weekday:")  
    totAmt = 0  
    for item in expense_list:  
        day = item[0]  
        amount = float(item[1])  
        category = item[2]  
        if day == "Monday":  
            totAmt += amount   
            print ("Monday: $",totAmt)
        elif day == 'Tuesday':
            totAmt += amount   
            print ("Tuesday: $",totAmt)
        elif day == 'Wednesday':
            totAmt += amount   
            print ("Wednesday: $",totAmt)
        elif day == 'Thursday':
            totAmt += amount   
            print ("Thursday: $",totAmt)
        elif day == 'Friday':
            totAmt += amount   
            print ("Friday: $",totAmt)
        elif day == 'Saturday':
            totAmt += amount   
            print ("Saturday: $",totAmt)
        else:
            totAmt += amount   
            print ("Sunday: $",totAmt)
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. It did help me to NOT get an error.
Unfortunately, this just found the first Monday entry and added it to itself 144 times with a float precision of 13.

Comment: @MagickalMemories Because, we only compare it with Monday, you will need to compare with every day in a week if you want to get the wanted output

Answer (score 0):

```
summary = {}

for day, money, category in expense_list:
    if day in summary:
        summary[day] = summary[day] + float(money)
    else:
        summary[day] = float(money)
for day in summary:
    summary[day] = "$" + str(summary[day])
    print(day + ": " + summary[day])
```

This will give you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: `dict.setdefault` or `collections.defaultdict` is usually the way to do this kind of task.

Comment: rajat:
I only got a single result with that.
Monday: $ 1181.7500000000036

Comment: @MagickalMemories I tested the code on the data sample that you posted and I got the correct result. I am not sure whats wrong on your side. 
Monday: $17.9
Tuesday: $4.95
Wednesday: $4.95
Thursday: $31.0
Friday: $70.0
Saturday: $35.5

Answer (score 0):

So, I found my answer.
Since you were all so kind as to help, I wanted to share it:
Note that this is not JUST the answer. I added a few basic print() lines to give it some rudimentary improvement.

```
print ("\n---------------------")  
print (" Summary by weekday")  
print ("---------------------")  
for weekday in ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']:  
    this_day_total = 0.0  
    for expense_item in expense_list:  
        if expense_item[0] == weekday:  
            this_day_total += float(expense_item[1])  
    print("%-9s: $%7.2f" % (weekday, this_day_total))  
print ("---------------------")
```

Thanks for trying to help, everyone!

Comment: This approach will work but it is not a good solution as the problem could be solved in O(n) time complexity. So this a solution, but not an optimal one.